# ES6/Babel version of binding to function of an object

Tags: javascript, this, ecmascript-6

How would I implement the same behaviour as below in es6

```
var grand_parent = {
  parent: {
     child: function () {
       // logic
     }.bind(this)
  }
}
```

I tired the following, but I got a syntax error.

```
var grand_parent = {
   parent: {
    child() {
      // logic
    }.bind(this)
  }
```

Comment: why do you bind your method to the global instead of `parent` in the first example? the behavior should be the same between 5/6, save "use strict" differences. i would think that inside `child`, you would want `this` to be `parent`, right? if so, you don't need to bind it at all, unless you want to externally apply it without context later...

Comment: Definitely need more of an example here. With the example, the answer is just that you can't because it's not what classes are designed to do.

Comment: It's not global.  This is just a simplified example of some react code I'm refactoring.

Comment: Well, it's just a regular Object, therefore you can't use `var`, but should use property names. Thats where the syntax error is coming from. On a side note, you can also use [fat arrows](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) instead of `bind()`

Comment: The syntax error is for the .bind()

Comment: ES5 syntax is valid in ES6 as well, so I'd go with whatever works in ES5. Only because there are new ways to define functions/methods in ES6 doesn't mean they have to be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would most likely use an arrow function:

```
var grand_parent = {
  parent: {
    child: () => {
      // logic
    }
  }
};
```

where `this` is lexically bound and works just as in your `.bind(this)` scenario.
You cannot call `.bind()` using the method syntax.